# Is it possible/interesting to recheck a RAID array online?

Tags: raid

ZDNET put a very controversial article about [RAID5 doomed in 2009](http://blogs.zdnet.com/storage/?p=162) because of bigger and bigger capacities some time ago (2007).

2009 has arrived and I would like to know if it's possible to recheck a RAID array online : read the whole discs and eventually detect a disk failure in advance (ie not subject to any SMART or data-needed basis).

I can think of a very simple way of checking : do a `dd if=/dev/md0 of=/dev/null` and monitor the RAID logs, but I'm searching of a more integrated way, that could even do some magic with the errors (like relocating them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux software RAID (md) in many distributions (debian & ubuntu at least) will often perform a resync monthly (first sunday) just in case; look for the "checkarray" script.

NetApp filer's (by default) do a low priority resync every sunday morning.

In practice I don't believe I've ever had either of these catch a problem even with hundreds of systems in production.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Incidently I am with Debian, have the checkarray script in crontab, but didn't know it was already running under the hood.

Comment: If you install something like the logcheck package you'll be e-mailed the "interesting" parts of syslog, such as the messages md prints while it does this.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern array controllers provide this as the controller level. Dell PERC raid controllers have something called "[Patrol Read](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/5.1/en/omss_ug/html/cntkpatm.html)" which exercises the disks in the array.

ZFS has a feature called "[resilvering](https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/entry/smokin_mirrors)" which does something similar.